# TCP level Redundancy Elimination

Tags: caching, tcp, network-protocols, http-caching, redundancy

What is TCP level redundancy elimination? Any paper to understand its technicalities?
Thanks in advance.
PS: Tried to google, but could not find a paper giver proper explanation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below URL has detailed information about how the TCP redundancy is implemented and its results on a 3G mobile network. It shows TCP redundancy provides more bandwidth saving than traditional web caches.

http://www.ndsl.kaist.edu/~kyoungsoo/papers/mobisys13_woo.pdf